# R: deparse(substitute(.)) not recognizing object or levels

Tags: r, function

I am writing a function to convert a factor variable into a series of binary indicators for each level of the factor and add those indicator to the original data frame. There are many packages for doing this, but I wanted to write my own function.

Shouldn't the below work regardless of whether the input to the factor_var() argument is "foo" or foo? Neither appear to work.

```
library(dplyr)

# Generate toy data
dat <- data.frame(x = seq(1:3), y = factor(5:7))

# Define function taking data frame containing factor_var to create dummies
to_dummy <- function(df = NULL, factor_var = NULL){
  var_name <- factor_var %>% substitute() %>% deparse()
  model.matrix(~ 0 + var_name, data = df) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::bind_cols(df)}

# Test function with object input to factor_vary argument
to_dummy(df = dat, factor_var = y)

# Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'y' not found 

# Test function with string input to factor_vary argument
to_dummy(df = dat, factor_var = "y")

# Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      dplyr::bind_cols(df)}
```

Comment: `to_dummy` function is incomplete - where is closing `}`?

Comment: @CPak oops, added the missing code.

Comment: You need special considerations when programming with `dplyr` because it uses non-standard evaluation, [check its vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).